# Android WebView not showing local IP address

Tags: java, android, webview, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running [WebIOPi](http://webiopi.trouch.com/), which is connected to a relay board to turn things on and off via a web-based interface.  Here's what the interface looks like in a browser:

[image]

Everything works fine, but I want to create an android app that would simply display the web-based interface via WebView.  I've used WebView before and it seems pretty straight forward, but I can't get it working.

Here's my code:

MainActivity:

```
package org.kevinbright.android.backyardcontrolapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebViewer;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);

    mWebViewer = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewer);
    mWebViewer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebViewer.clearCache(true);
    mWebViewer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebViewer.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.100:8000/");
}
}
```

Here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<WebView android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/webviewer"/>
```

And I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to the Manifest.

I don't get any logcat errors, but when I run the app, I get only a white screen.  Also, if I substitute "http://www.google.com", everything works fine.  Also, I'm testing on a live device (no emulator).  Any suggestions as to why this isn't working?

Comment: that should load if u have all the requisite permissions set on the webView and if used , on the webVwClient... u will need to debug the java up until the webView's load()  ... then shift debugger to chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1):

if you're using http protocol, try to add this on your android manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

it works for me

Comment: This question is from 2016, where this wasn't required.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.clearCache(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/SampleWebServer/Welcome.html");
        //pass complete url 
       
}
```

Comment: Please explain why it should be the complete url. That would be nice to clear about whether there is any difference between using browser and WebView in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like yours. I've achieved load a local IP, but it takes at least 30 seconds, meanwhile white screen as you. It loooks like chromium (webView) try to find the IP on internet, and at the end said: "oh, it's a local ip, let's load". It's quite weird. I keep on waiting for help as well.

Comment: Well I've solved my problem. In fact, it wasn't like yours, because I tried to connect with my local server in a local network without internet connection. And my problem was I had an external reference in my stylesheet (@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css...). This stupid thing takes me a lot of time.
I've checked your code, and it's like my code. I can not help you. Luck!